# PySpark assign names to a column values 'withcolumn'

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am new to PySaprk but have some experience with R.

Question: I wanted to assign a name to the height (numbers) listed in ONE column. I started writing code as below:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("student_id")
df_enc_hw = df_enc_hw.withColumn("stuname", \
                       when(lower(col("height")) <= 4, "under_ht") 
                      .when(lower(col("height")) > 4 < 5, "ok_ht")  
                      .when(lower(col("height")) >=5 < 6, "normal_ht")  
                      .when(lower(col("height")) >=6, "abnor_ht"))
```

**But the following error:**

```
    633 
    634     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 635         raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
    636                          "'~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.")
    637     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Thank you for your help
K

Comment: Change `lower(col("height")) > 4 < 5` to `(lower(col("height")) > 4) & (lower(col("height")) < 5)` (the same for the other conditions). It's a problem of operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

You should split up your conditionals into separate expressions like this:

```
df_enc_hw = df_enc_hw.withColumn("stuname", \
                       when(lower(col("height")) <= 4, "under_ht") 
                      .when((lower(col("height")) > 4) & (lower(col("height")) < 5), "ok_ht")  
                      .when((lower(col("height")) >=5) & (lower(col("height")) < 6), "normal_ht")  
                      .when(lower(col("height")) >=6, "abnor_ht"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much fro your time and help. It is working :)